# Login and destroy multiples bot

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

I am trying to use multiples bots to create some sort of discussion in a channel but I keep getting "Request to use token, but token was unavailable to the client." I think it's because I login and destroy the bot too fast...

code:

```
function MSG() {
  
    var msg = [
        "msg1",
        "msg2",
        "msg3"
    ];

    var id = [
        "id1",
        "id2",
        "id3",
        "id4",
        "id5",
        "id6",
    ];

    let trg = Math.floor(Math.random() * msg.length);  
    let trg2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * id.length);  

    const bot = new Discord.Client();
    bot.login(id[trg2])

    let msgchannel = bot.channels.cache.get('channel id');
    if(msgchannel){
        
        msgchannel.send(msg[trg])
        console.log(msg[trg])
    }
    bot.destroy()
}

(function loop() {
    var temps = Math.floor(Math.random() * 7000 + 3000); 
        console.log(temps)
            setTimeout(function() {
                MSG();
            loop();  
    }, temps);
}());
```

When i use this code, messages are sent on the different bots but only 5-6 then it stop for no reason

```
function MSG() {
  
    var msg = [
        "msg1",
        "msg2",
        "msg3"
    ];

    var id = [
        "id1",
        "id2",
        "id3",
        "id4",
        "id5",
        "id6",
    ];
    let trg = Math.floor(Math.random() * msg.length);  
    let trg2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * id.length);  

    bot.login(id[trg2])

    let msgchannel = bot.channels.cache.get('channel id');
    if(msgchannel){
        msgchannel.send(msg[trg])
        console.log(msg[trg])
    }

}

(function loop() {
    var temps = Math.floor(Math.random() * 7000 + 3000); 
        console.log(temps)
            setTimeout(function() {
                MSG();
            loop();  
    }, temps);
}());
```

Answer (score 0):

Client, when successfully logged in, triggers an event called [`ready`](https://discord.js.org/?source=post_page---------------------------#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-ready), simply have your code wait until the bot is ready to use - then call the function, and finally destroy the bot.

EDIT: Alternatively, use `async/await` to wait for your bot to successfully log in (I think in your case that would be the easier/better solution).